# Given the $2^n$ primorial divisors, $D(5\#) = \{ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30\}$, why are there always exactly $2^n$ different divisor indicator vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, prime-numbers, divisibility, conjectures

Define $D(m)$ to be the (**ordered**) set of divisors of $m \in \Bbb{N}$.

Let $m = p_n\# = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots p_n$.  Clearly, $|D(m)| = $ the number of divisors of $p_n\# = 2^n$.

Now define a **divisor indicator vector at $x$** to be $\langle (d \mid x) : d \in D(m) \rangle$ where $(d \mid x) = \begin{cases} 1, \text{ if } d \mid x \\ 0, \text{ if } d \nmid x \end{cases}$; for any given $x \in \Bbb{Z}$.

> **Conjecture 1.** The number of possible divisor indicator vectors is precisely $2^n$.

For example:

```
1 2 3 5 6 10 15 30
1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0
1 1 0 0 0 0  0  0 
1 0 1 0 0 0  0  0
1 0 0 1 0 0  0  0
1 1 1 0 1 0  0  0 
1 1 0 1 0 1  0  0 
1 0 1 1 0 0  1  0
1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1
```

I.e. there are $8$ divisors so the number of divisor indicator vectors is also $8$.  Clearly it's since if $15 \mid x$ then both $3 \mid x$ and $5\mid x$ and vise-versa, since $\gcd(3,5) = 1$, but how would the argument go for the general case?

My next question which I think is better is about this conjecture:

> **Conjecture 2.** The set of all possible divisor indicator vectors is linearly independent over any field.

I say any field because every field by definition contains the values of the divisor indicator $(d \mid \cdot)$ or $0$ and $1$.  So for each field $F$ you'd define $(d\mid \cdot) : \Bbb{Z} \to \{0, 1\} \subset F$.

Now this might have something to do with the first conjecture since our degrees of freedom are precisely determined by the $n$ primes involved and taken together (just the prime components):

```
2 3 5 
1 0 0 
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

we have clear linear independence.

What is the easiest & most elegant way you can think of to prove both of these conjectures?

Answer (score 1):

**Proof of 1.**  For any given $x \in \Bbb{Z}$ there are $2^n$ possibilities: either $2 \mid x$ or it doesn't, either $3\mid x$ or it doesn't, $\dots \ $, either $p_n \mid x$ or it doesn't. The answer to the divisibility by each of the $p_i$ completely determines the rest of the vector's entries, by CRT you could say.

**Proof of 2.**  Let $X$ be a finite set of $2^n$ representatives $x \in X$ so that $\langle (d \mid x) : d \in D(p_n\#)\rangle, \ x \in X$ ranges over all possible divisor indicator vectors.  Suppose that:

$$
\sum_{d \mid p_n\#} c_d \cdot (d \mid x) = 0, \forall x \in X
$$

Note this is the same thing as saying $A\overline{c} = 0$ where $A_{i,j} = (d_i \mid x_j)$ where $d_i$ is the $i$th divisor in the (ordered) set $D = D(p_n\#)$ and $x_j =$ the $j$th entry in $X$ (in any fixed order).  And where $\overline{c} = \langle c_d : d \in D\rangle^T$.  So, what's left to prove is that $c_d = 0$ for all $d \in D$.  Let's also index the entries of $X$ by elements of $D$.  Clearly, there exists some $x_1 \in X$ such that: $c_1(1\mid x_1) = c_1 = 0$ by definition of $X$ as a full set of representatives.

Now, if for any divisor $d \in D$ we have that $c_1(1\mid x_1) + c_d(d\mid x_d) = 0$, and $(d\mid x_d) = 1$, then we have $c_d = -c_1 = 0$.  Thus for each prime $p \in D$ we have that $c_p = 0$.  Now for all $d \in D$ such that $\Omega(d) = 2$ we have (for some $x \in X$ by definition):

$$
c_1(1\mid x) + c_2(2 \mid x) + c_3(3\mid x) + c_6(6 \mid x) = 0
$$

for example.  But the first $3$ terms have already been shown to zero out, implying that $c_6 = 0$ as well.  Clearly this generalizes to any $\Omega(d) = 2$.  Next perform a similar proof for when $\Omega(d) = 3$ and so on...

You might make it more elegant via formal induction, but I believe this proof is good enough.  $\blacksquare$

Comment: According to a commenter in another post, you might be able to take other sets of divisors (perhaps any) and get linear independence amongst their functions.